# Swift search bar - updating table view with Alamofire request

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've made up some string search on my database and i return the JSON after the user pushes the 3rd character on search bar, after that I append all the results to an Array and it fills a tableview with data.

Although I'm dealing with an issue. When I search lets say for `mens` I get the results appear on the tableview

If i delete all the text and i write women, all good... but when i'm deleting some strings etc i get an error `index out of range` inside the tableview cellForRowAt. I guess that it breaks cause the tableview doesn't have the time to get the appended array and fill the cells.

What I'm trying to find out is how can i make it work, WITHOUT setting a time delay on the query or in the `reloadData()`. The reason I don't want time delay is because some user's might have a slow - old iPhone and even with 2 sec delay, it could crash.

This is my code

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var searchResultTable: UITableView!
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    var filteredData = [Products]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchResultTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    }


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }


    func getSearch(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete, searchString: String) {
        if filteredData.isEmpty == false {
            filteredData.removeAll()
        }
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "action" : "search",
            "subaction" : "get",
            "product_name"  : searchString,
            "limit" : "0,30"
        ]


        Alamofire.request(baseurl, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let result = responseData.result

                if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                    if let list = dict["product_details"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                        for obj in list {
                            let manPerfumes = Products(productDict: obj)
                            self.filteredData.append(manPerfumes)
                        }


                    }
                }
                completed()
            }
        }
    }


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 170
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return filteredData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell:iPhoneTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "iPhoneTableCell", for: indexPath) as! iPhoneTableViewCell

            let prods = self.filteredData[indexPath.row] //HERE I GET THE ERROR
            cell.configureCell(products: prods)

            return cell

    }

}

extension SearchViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        if (searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count)! >= 3 {
                    self.getSearch(completed: {
                    self.searchResultTable.reloadData()

                    self.searchResultTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
                }, searchString: searchController.searchBar.text!)
        } else {
            self.searchResultTable.reloadData()
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are changing the state of `filteredData` while the tableView does `reloadData`.  If `numberOfRowsForSection` returns 3, and then the user hits the delete key for example, the array size will become 0.  That may be why `cellForRow` throws an exception when requesting indices 0,1 or 2.